# Unable to Print or Save Predicted Results in Orange?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, prediction, orange

I have applied some models (Logistic, Tree, SVM, Neural Network, etc) in order to predict my results. However, when I printed or saved my predicted results, I was unable to print the Complete predicted Instances or rows. While in Orange, predicted result to display all and Complete instances but was unable to save or print the same results.

Here is a screen shot:

[image]

See the printed results (+52 more) but is unable to see these +52 instances.

Comment: May I know which programming language you are using here?

Comment: @ Kalyan Prasad, Well, I am Using GUI of Orange Software